# assign dictionary key's value to another variable

Tags: python

```
grammar = {
'expert' : {
'min_time' : 30,
'filtered_thresholds' : {'A':10,'B':10,'C':10,'D':10,'E':20,'I':10,'T':10,'H':10,'K':0,'J':0,'L':0,'M':0,'N':0,'O':0,'P':0,'Q':0,'R':0,'S':0},
'filter_screens' : ['H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S']
},

'expert2' : {
'min_time' : 2,
'filtered thresholds' : {'A':10,'B':10,'C':10,'D':10,'E':20,'I':10,'T':10,'H':10,'K':0,'J':0,'L':0,'M':0,'N':0,'O':0,'P':0,'Q':0,'R':0,'S':0},
'filter screens' : ['H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S']
 } 
}
for i in grammar:
    for j in grammar[i]:
        min_time = j['min_time']
        filtered_thresholds_expert = j['filtered_thresholds']
        filtered_screens = j['filtered_screens']
        ProcessThresholds(time_per_screen_percentage)
```

I want to assign 'min_time' to min_time, 'filtered_thresholds' to filtered_thresholds_expert and 'filtered_screens' to filtered_screens.
I however get this error

> min_time = j['min_time']
>   TypeError: string indices must be integers, not str

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need the inner loop.

```
for i in grammar:
    j = grammar[i]
    min_time = j['min_time']
    filtered_thresholds_expert = j['filtered_thresholds']
    filtered_screens = j['filtered_screens']
    ProcessThresholds(time_per_screen_percentage)
```

And you can further polish it to

```
for key, j in grammar.iteritems():
    ...
```

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a nested loop there.  You end up iterating over the keys of your inner dictionaries, so when you get to the error line, `j` is just the string `'min_time'` rather than that dictionary entry.  I've fixed up your code a bit so it doesn't mix spaces and underscores in your keys.  See if this works for you.

```
grammar = {
'expert' : {
'min_time' : 30,
'filtered_thresholds' : {'A':10,'B':10,'C':10,'D':10,'E':20,'I':10,'T':10,'H':10,'K':0,'J':0,'L':0,'M':0,'N':0,'O':0,'P':0,'Q':0,'R':0,'S':0},
'filter_screens' : ['H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S']
},

'expert2' : {
'min_time' : 2,
'filtered_thresholds' : {'A':10,'B':10,'C':10,'D':10,'E':20,'I':10,'T':10,'H':10,'K':0,'J':0,'L':0,'M':0,'N':0,'O':0,'P':0,'Q':0,'R':0,'S':0},
'filter_screens' : ['H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S']
 } 
}
for i in grammar:
    j = grammar[i]
    min_time = j['min_time']
    filtered_thresholds_expert = j['filtered_thresholds']
    filtered_screens = j['filter_screens']
    ProcessThresholds(time_per_screen_percentage)
```

Answer (score 1):

You've got a couple of problems:

First, there's no apparent reason why `grammar` is a dictionary: you iterate it but never index it by key, so it could be a list. Second, you only need one loop. Try this:

```
grammar = [
{
'min_time' : 30,
'filtered_thresholds' : {'A':10,'B':10,'C':10,'D':10,'E':20,'I':10,'T':10,'H':10,'K':0,'J':0,'L':0,'M':0,'N':0,'O':0,'P':0,'Q':0,'R':0,'S':0},
'filter_screens' : ['H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S']
},

{
'min_time' : 2,
'filtered thresholds' : {'A':10,'B':10,'C':10,'D':10,'E':20,'I':10,'T':10,'H':10,'K':0,'J':0,'L':0,'M':0,'N':0,'O':0,'P':0,'Q':0,'R':0,'S':0},
'filter screens' : ['H','I','J','K','L','M','N','O','P','Q','R','S']
 } 
]

for i in grammar:
    min_time = i['min_time']
    filtered_thresholds_expert = i['filtered_thresholds']
    filtered_screens = i['filter_screens']
    ProcessThresholds(time_per_screen_percentage)
```